# trackpad pinch/unpinch w/ javascript (MacBook)

Tags: javascript, multi-touch

I am trying to use native javascript - no jQuery, that is.  Pinch and Unpinch but not for zoom out/in.  It is good on iOS and android using touches, etc.  But I do not know how to "emulate" this behavior for my Mac-book's trackpad.  Any help to get me started off in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

At least in Chrome, trackpad "pinch-to-zoom" triggers a wheel/mousewheel event that appears as though the ctrl key is pressed. You can capture this event just like any other wheel/mousewheel event and prevent its default from occurring. Here is an example using jQuery:

```
$("canvas").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // perform desired zoom action here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Starting from Safari 9.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH10-SW7) you can catch zoom and rotation events from **OSX devices**. For more information read the [GestureEvent Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/GestureEventClassReference/index.html). Note that this only works in Safari but since your question was about your "**Mac-book's trackpad**" I think this is what you are looking for.

---

Side note: these events are also supported in Safari on iOS.